# How do I pull the user_about_me section from Facebook Javascript login SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook

We can't seem to pull the user_about_me section from the Facebook Javascript login SDK. The code looks right (you can view it here: https://gist.github.com/dmitryhawk/48cf7a20153924f80968 ). Our permission was approved.

Can't figure this one out; any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Which API call are you doing to get that information and what is not working?

Comment: So we are using the request below. Our issue is that most accounts will not properly pull the "user_about_me" field.

Comment: scope list (requested params):scope:'public_profile,email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_friends,read_friendlists,user_hometown,user_education_history'
version    : 'v2.2'
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"

Comment: We've noticed something strange where one russian account > http://i.imgur.com/lVdtNaE.png << it will return "bio" with "about me" another USA account > http://i.imgur.com/N4qbbG1.png << it will not return "bio".

Answer (score 0):

WizKid...thanks for the response (I am a teammate of Thomas Bradley who made the above post). So we are using the request below. Our issue is that most accounts will not properly pull the "user_about_me" field.

```
scope list (requested params):scope:'public_profile,email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_friends,read_friendlists,user_hometown,user_education_history'
version    : 'v2.2'
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"
```

We've noticed something strange where one russian account > https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJKK3.png << it will return "bio" with "about me"
another USA account > https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsWd6.png << it will not return "bio".